# Changed http to https on database, now 404 on admin page

Tags: php, wordpress

The problem: I changed both the home url and the site url in the wp-options table inside the database (using wordpress). I only changed the "http" for the "https" part (the site has an active SSL certificate). After that, I would get a 404 error every time I tried to go to https://example.com/wp-admin. Everything else seemed okay.

Here is the list of things I have tried so far:

- Added this line `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` in the wp-config.php
- Checked related steps here https://websitesetup.org/http-to-https-wordpress/
- Went back to the database and changed everything back (changed it from https to http) but the problem remains.

I would really appreciate the help. Thank you in advance.

(I'm aware this question has been asked many other times, but I just can't make it work).

Comment: you changed http to https also on `wp-config.php`?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering. Yes, I forgot to add it to my question. I added this lines to my wp-config.php `define('WP_HOME','https://www.example.com');` and `define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.example.com');`

Comment: Have you checked the .htaccess file

Comment: Yes, this is the content of my `.htaccess` file.

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>`

Comment: did you verify you can manually hit the https version?

Answer (score 0):

Does your site remove the index.php ? in which case WP loads a custom .htaccess file. You may want to take  look at this: -
https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747758-Force-your-site-to-load-securely-with-an-htaccess-file

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. My site does remove the index.php part. I am actually forcing my site to load on https from the .htaccess file. But still no luck.

Comment: maybe the issue is in the Mysql table, I found this https://uk.godaddy.com/help/reset-wordpress-permalinks-in-the-database-26352

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the replies. I followed your advice but was unable to gain access to the backend of the site. I ended up going back to a previous version of the database.

To anyone wondering, I did this by going to the "Server Rewind" option in the cPanel under the "Files" section. I then clicked on the tab "Restore Databases" and selected the date and database that I needed to recover.

Finally, don't forget to check the "Overwrite existing database" checkbox before you go ahead and click "Restore".

Note: If you don't see any databases show up or you are unable to find this section it may be because your host provider does not include this function in the hosting package you purchased.